error: linker `cc` not found
Я решил начать изучать язык Rust и столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
При попытке запустить код, "cargo run", "cargo build" выдаёт такую ошибку:
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: could not compile `projectlearn` (bin "projectlearn") due to 1 previous error

Cargo.toml выглядит так:
name = "projectlearn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]


Linux Manjaro GNOME

Ну так поставьте линкер-то...

хорошо, только как это сделать, я то не знаю @PavelMayorov

если есть мета-пакет build-essential, ставьте сразу его - он по зависимостям подтянет всё самое необходимое для компиляции как таковой.

вроде в arch это base-devel: https://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/2800

Спасибо, помогло! @aleksandrbarakin

Если есть мета-пакет build-essential, ставьте сразу его - он по зависимостям подтянет всё самое необходимое для компиляции как таковой.
В Arch это base-devel: myridia.com/dev_posts/view/2800
